# Ограничение доступа к сайту

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Можно ли сделать сайт выложенный на хостинг доступным только с одного, двух ip  адресов? Знаю что с помощью .htaccess можно скрыть из доступа некоторые части приложения уже когда оно в общем доступе на сервере, но можно ли скрыть приложение для всех кроме команды тестирования ?

UPD

Попробовал, как советовали уважаемые коллеги так :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from -my ip adress
```

В итоге 403 вылетает даже мне самому.

Comment: Можно, для дальнейшего совета раскройте тайну что за ОС(Windows\Linux), что за сервер? (Apache?)

Comment: На том же apache можно не скрывать, а поставить basic авторизацию. Никто посторонний не пройдёт

Comment: @ArchDemon на том же апаче можно ограничить доступ для нескольких IP, так же с помощью IPTables можно открыть доступ с нескольких IP, так же в стандартном брандмауере винды можно открыть доступ с определенных IP. Вопрос что именно установленно у автора.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону `Авторизация с помощью htaccess и htpasswd`? или не то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно, заблокировать доступ по ip. Например:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.
Allow from .localnet
Allow from admin.somewhere.in.the.net
```

Данный код запретит доступ для всех, кроме сети 192.168.0.0/24, всех хостов, DNS имя которых содержит .localnet, а также хоста, DNS имя которого admin.somewhere.in.the.net. 
Думаю поможет http://htaccess.ru/info/ip-filtering/

Answer (score 2):

Если не хотите пока заморачиваться настройкой iptables на сервере, можно для начала создать файл .htaccess в каталоге с сайтом и прописать в нем:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from x.x.x.x
```

Где x.x.x.x - ваш ip. Можно добавить целиком весь диапазон ip, указав первые три цифры x.x.x
Вы можете использовать команду allow много раз перечислив сколько нужно ip адресов

```
Allow from x.x.x.x
Allow from y.y.y.y
```

и т.д.